# ¿Cómo reduzco el lag que traen las imágenes?

Tags: android, android-studio, imagen, image-view, lag

**DESCRIPCIÓN**

Tengo una actividad (con scroll view) en la cual muestro **9 Image Views (width = match_parent, height = 100dp)**. Antes colocaba las imágenes por medio de su url con Glide (las extraía de Google). Decidí descargarlas y colocarlas en drawable y a partir de ahí la actividad se me comenzó a laggear al deslizar el Scroll.

**¿QUÉ INTENTÉ?**

1- Creé una carpeta drawable-xxhdpi en donde coloqué las imágenes pero el problema no se solucionó.

2- Reduje el peso de las imágenes con una página web (https://compressjpeg.com/es/) pero al descargarlas y colocarlas de nuevo en drawable, el problema no se soluciona.

**PREGUNTA Y DATOS ADICIONALES**

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?. Quiero poder conservar las imágenes en mis carpetas drawable para poder ponérselas a los image views mediante la **etiqueta xml src**.

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

### EDIT (01/12/2020)

Acabo de sumar el peso de las 9 imágenes. Entre todas suman 992KB (1 MB). ¿Cómo puede ser que, aún con tan poco peso, la actividad se me tilde?.

¿Hay un límite de peso establecido por android studio, o algo por el estilo?

Comment: Hola y gracias por responder. No hay código. Estoy trabajando con image views y drawable. Le pongo la imagen por medio de src. Si necesitas ver algo son las imagenes jpg que no quiero mostrarlas.    <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_persona"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/img_persona"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

Comment: Para eso crea AsyncTask o algún otro mecanismo para que liberes al hilo principal o de interfaz, ya que por muchas instrucciones está haciendo que el hilo se bloquee.

Comment: Glide usa un hilo en background, por eso no se lagea el scroll.

Comment: 1. Utiliza RecyclerView y DiffUtil para las actualizaciones de la data. 2. Para cargar las imágenes Drawable, debes hacer un tipo de Caching o Reciclar los bitmaps junto con el evento de onViewRecycled. 3. Debes cargar todas las resoluciones de las imágenes hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi y Android decidirá cuál cargar dependiendo de la resolución del dispositivo. 4. Utiliza Glide para cargar las imágenes Drawable, Glide no solo se utiliza para cargar imágenes alojadas en la nube, también sirve para cargar recursos locales e incluso puedes hacer todos los puntos anteriores con más simpleza.

Comment: Gracias a todos por responder. Maximiliano y OsAndNoTi a que se refieren con "hilo". Podrían ser mas especificos?. @Andrespengineer si no es mucho pedir podrias elaborar una respuesta detallando cada punto? es bastante técnico para mis conocimientos

Comment: Puedes ver mis respuestas para entender por que se puede ocasionar el Lag cargando imagenes y otros problemas que pueden surgir: [Evitar LAG y OOM cargando imagenes](https://shorturl.at/inrxH) [Cachear imagen y persistencia](https://shorturl.at/ejkxA) [Problemas con carga de imagenes locales con Glide](https://shorturl.at/aklZ6) y [Aqui puedes ver un ejemplo de como implementar DiffUtil](https://shorturl.at/opALX). Actualmente no tengo una base de codigo para poder hacerte un ejemplo elaborado, si tienes algo desarrollado compartelo. Saludos.

Comment: hilo son secuncias de tareas, va con el procesador busca mas info. Lo q te hace lagear es seguro la memoria, por las resoluciones de las imagenes y el hecho de que usas un scrollview y no un recyclerview